# Function within a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have submit function on a button. Upon clicking "submit" a dialog box pops and asks for confirmation and after clicking "ok" the form is submitted.

Now I want to add another function in which upon clicking "ok" the form should be submitted & background color of page should also change. The code I wrote is given below. **but now even the form is not submitting. Help needed!**

```
function myfunction(e)
    {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
            function changecolor(){
                backgroundcolor: #0065bd;
            }
            changecolor();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `camelCase`, use underscores to deliminate your function names as standards should use camelCase and you don't want to negate standard functions as they are released.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the `changecolor` function on global. No need to add inside the another function.And pass data from first function to second function via params

**updated**

change the color value via `classList.add`

```
function myfunction(e) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
    changecolor(e); //pass anything
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function changecolor(e) { //receive
  e.target.classList.add('custom_back')
}
```

**css:** *updated the code on your `style.css`*

```
.custom_back{
   backgroundcolor: #0065bd !important;
}
```

Comment: tried it, but still the page does not change to #0065bd after submission

Comment: ok. where did you updated the colour form or body tag?

Comment: .custom_back{
   backgroundcolor: #0065bd !important;
}   This was updated in css file

Answer (score 0):

Your `changecolor` function occurs error. To fix it, you need to change background color in JavaScript way.

```
function myfunction(e)
{
   if(!confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
       e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#0065bd";
   } else {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: the color does not change to #0065BD (blue). can it be because that it is declared as white in CSS (the color of page before submitting form?

Answer (score 0):

You're over-thinking it.

HTML:

```
<input onclick="submit_form(event);" type="submit" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function submit_form(event)
{
 if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?'))
 {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#0065bd';
  event.target.setAttribute('disabled','true');
 }
 else {event.preventDefault();}//user decided not to submit form.
}
```

Additionally you can simply style disabled elements using CSS negating having to manually set the `background-color` via JavaScript:

```
[disabled] {background-color = '#0065bd';}
```